# `LOW` being defined as `0` and `HIGH` being defined as `1` - is this a part of external specification?

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, digital

`Arduino.h` defines `LOW` as `0x0` and `HIGH` as `0x1`. Does the Arduino API intend to expose that fact? Does it guarantee that this will always be that way?

In other words, what is the intended purpose of these manifest constants: `LOW` and `HIGH`?

- Is this purely cosmetic mnemonics added as an alternative for `0/1` and `false/true`, for those who like `LOW/HIGH` better?
- Or is this an attempt to abstract/isolate the user's source code from the actual representation of `LOW` and `HIGH` (e.g. in case the representation changes in the future)?

The underlying reason for this question is to figure out whether code like

```
digitalWrite(some_pin, true);
digitalWrite(some_other_pin, !digitalRead(some_other_pin));
```

is a good programming practice. (If `LOW` and `HIGH` are there to abstract the user's code form their actual values then code like that is definitely a bad programming practice.)

Comment: Couldn't it be both?

Comment: @jose can u c: It could. But the truly critical part here is whether the answer to the *second* point is "yes".

Comment: Looking at the precursor to Arduino framework, [WConstants.h](https://github.com/WiringProject/Wiring/blob/da0b6b9282ae6a3f047235b5a91b6df567fdf22f/framework/cores/Common/WConstants.h#L39) seems to have a commented out `0xFF` as a potential definition of `HIGH`, so point 2 may be the case...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The underlying reason for this question is to figure out whether code like
>
> ```
> digitalWrite(some_pin, true);
> digitalWrite(some_other_pin, !digitalRead(some_other_pin));
> ```
>
> is a good programming practice. (If LOW and HIGH are there to abstract the user's code form their actual values then code like that is definitely a bad programming practice.)

Strictly speaking, no, that is not good programming practice.

`digitalRead()` returns an `int`. `digitalWrite()` expects an `int`.  Using `!` converts the `int` into a `bool` and then it's promoted back to an `int` again.

In fact, the "next gen" Arduino core API changes HIGH and LOW from a simple `int` to an `enum` - and that struggles with casting through `bool` like that:

```
typedef enum {
  LOW     = 0,
  HIGH    = 1,
  CHANGE  = 2,
  FALLING = 3,
  RISING  = 4,
} PinStatus;
```

You can see the problems that causes [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/63624/cannot-convert-bool-to-pinstatus-for-argument-2-to-void-digitalwritepin).